# How to open a file from network location?

Tags: workflow, image, blend-files, file-browser

My working directory is on a network location. Within Blenders file browser I can only choose between hard disks at the moment:

[image]

How can I access **blend-files** or **images** on a network location?

*I am using blender v2.76 on windows 8*

Comment: what version of blender are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: What about setting up a network drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the shared folder is accessible form your machine, i.e. you are already logged  to the share and can access it on the OS, you can type the IP address (or Computer Name) and share name in the address bar.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a solution for linux as well ?

Comment: Just found it. I added an answer (didn't actually verify on Win and Mac but I don't see why it wouldn't work).

Answer (score 1):

On any operating system (Windows, Linux, Mac) :

- open the shared folder from your file explorer (not in blender)
- open a .blend file located in this folder
- in Blender, click on File > Open

In the address bar, you should see the location of the blend file you just opened, that gives you the template.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an old entry but hopefully this can help someone with problems accessing a Windows 10 shared network drive from Blender running on an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.

1) Ensure you can see the Windows shared disk in your Linux file explorer (share the disk on Windows and access this on Linux using SMB:// etc.).

2) Right click on the Windows shared disk in the Linux file explorer and select "Open in Terminal". If you don't see the "Open in Terminal" option in the list, left click on the disk to see the contents of the Windows shared disk and then go back one page, you should now see the option. 
[image]

3) A Terminal session will be openend on the Windows shared disk. 
[image]

4) Copy the blue text (which is the link to Windows shared disk from Linux) and paste this in the "File path" field in Blender Open file window. You should now see all the relevant folders and blend files in the Windows shared disk.

Hope this helps someone. 
Most likely there are other ways go get the same done but i found this pretty easy.